# How to identify which Millennium Falcon set I have?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I bought a bundle of Lego from someone. She said that included among it was a Millennium Falcon. I have separated a lot of grey and obvious parts, but now I have discovered that I don't actually know what set it is. How can I find out?

Comment: Unless you have 10 to 11 kilos of bricks in mostly greys you can exclude the UCS Falcon right from the start.

Comment: Clear pictures of (well lit) uncommon parts could greatly enhance your question.

Comment: Howdy Rebecca.  Including some pictures for this would make it a lot easier for the folks on this site to help you.  You might be surprised at what we can figure out with a little more information.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Brick Land](https://www.thebrickland.com/lego-millennium-falcon-review/) the Millennium Falcon has appeared in over 25 sets. So there are several different possibilities. You can look up the sets on a page such as [BrickLink](https://bricklink.com) to see which parts are in which sets. Then you can find the rare / unique bricks and compare with the bricks you have.

Comment: Couple of special pieces to look for: Some cone- or circle-shaped piece(s) that could be (part off) the Falcon's cockpit. And don't forget mini-figs. A lot of the Falcon sets had some (varying) mini-figs that can pin it down to a specific set.